# visual basic random line from text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, generator

I need to create a Description Generator.

I have 3 text files and on each line in these files, I have a piece of description.

My program should be able to read all of these 3 files, then chose a random line from each file and combine them like that:

```
Result = RandomLineFile1 + RandomLineFile2 + RandomLineFile3
```

I have already implemented "Variables" in these piece of descriptions called: BRAND and MODEL.

My program should be able now to find these variables in the `TextBox3.Text` and replace them with the content of `TextBox1.Text` for Brand and `TextBox2.Text` for Model.

That's all.

Something like this:

```
readfile1(getrandomline)
add to TextBox3.Text
readfile2(getrandomline)
add to TextBox3.Text
readfile2(getrandomline)
add to TextBox3.Text
Find BRAND
Replace with TextBox1.Text
Find MODEL
Replace with TextBox2.Text
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Seems like you are having more than one problem. I'm not sure where exactly you are having trouble... Are you able to open a file and read the lines? Are you able to get a random number?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Post the code you've already written and we'll be happy to give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

FloatingKiwi,sad for having such a "nice" offensive answer on my first question on stackoverflow.
I was just asking for any kind of help ,not for the code it self.

I did it anyway,maybe will help somebody else:

```
On Error Resume Next
        TextBox1.Clear()
        Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Descriere\a.txt")
        Dim lines As New List(Of String)
        Dim rnd As New Random()
        Dim line As Integer
        While ioFile.Peek <> -1
            lines.Add(ioFile.ReadLine())
        End While
        line = rnd.Next(lines.Count + 1)
        TextBox1.AppendText(lines(line).Trim())
        ioFile.Close()
        ioFile.Dispose()
        Dim ioFile2 As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Descriere\core.txt")
        Dim lines2 As New List(Of String)
        Dim rnd2 As New Random()
        Dim line2 As Integer
        While ioFile2.Peek <> -1
            lines2.Add(ioFile2.ReadLine())
        End While
        line2 = rnd2.Next(lines2.Count + 1)
        TextBox1.AppendText(lines2(line2).Trim())
        ioFile2.Close()
        ioFile2.Dispose()
        Dim ioFile3 As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Descriere\x.txt")
        Dim lines3 As New List(Of String)
        Dim rnd3 As New Random()
        Dim line3 As Integer
        While ioFile3.Peek <> -1
            lines3.Add(ioFile3.ReadLine())
        End While
        line3 = rnd3.Next(lines3.Count + 1)
        TextBox1.AppendText(lines3(line3).Trim())
        ioFile3.Close()
        ioFile3.Dispose()
        TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "BRAND", TextBox2.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "MODEL", TextBox3.Text)
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        count = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Length - 1
        Label5.Text = "Caractere:" & Len(TextBox1.Text)
```